# Prove that this assumption doesn't work for all binary search trees

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

(Binary search tree is a binary tree where each node can have 2 children atmost, the right being larger than the node, and the left should be smaller than the node.)

I have a theory that i want to disprove. It says that for any binary tree, the if we take a search path (call it S) to a leaf node, then any node on the LEFT of S must be smaller than any node on S, and any node of the RIGHT must be larger than any node on S. In other words: node on left < node on S < node on right. Is there any counter-example to disprove this theory?

[For example if we have this tree:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0nl8.jpg)

A search path for node K would be M->F->H->K

The set of nodes on the left contains C, A, D, G

The set on the right contains V,S,P,T,X,W

What is a good counter example?

Thank you.

Comment: You have a strange definition of "right" and "left".. Surely `C, A, D, G` are to the **left** of `M->F-H->K`?

Comment: Any node on the left side of M->F-H->K (the search path) belongs to the "left" set. Anything on the right belongs to the "right" set.

Comment: So "The set of nodes on the right contains C, A, D, G" is incorrect, yes?

Comment: Yes. Im so sorry. I meant "LEFT".

Comment: Anyway, counter-example: `M->F->C->A`. The `D` node is the right of the line, but is not larger than `M` or `F`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but it wouldn't fit in a comment...

I think your definition of "binary search tree" is a bit lacking - after all, this would meet your definition:

```
   B
    \
     C
    / \
   A   D
```

However, that's not a true binary search tree - your definition lacks the recursive relationship. In a binary search tree, all elements in the left subtree of a node are less than the node label, and all elements in the right subtree are greater - not just the immediate children.

Perhaps having a more precise definition would help you in thinking about your "theory".

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't clear, but yeah this doesn't work. We insert B then C, but when we insert A it should be left to B. So we always start from the root and go down recursively. Sorry again.